# How to use this earphone jack on the breadboard?

Tags: breadboard

i do my project and i have a component earphone jack PJ-319

The schematic is below

[image]

[image]

[image]

In breadboard how can i get output signal? What pin i must use?? i can't know.

Comment: when you are not sure, a good way is to take a 3.5mm stereo plug, insert it, and simply check it out with a multimeter. Then make a little sketch in your log book, and you won't have to ask online.

Comment: You won't get this thing into a breadboard, mechanically: The holes in the breadboard don't fit the pins!

Answer (score 2):

When you insert a plug, the tip of the plug will be connected to pin 3. The ring will be connected to pin 2. Pin 4 (tip switch) will be disconnected when a plug is inserted.

When there is no plug inserted, pin 3 will be connected to pin 4 (for example to detect when/if a plug is inserted). All of this is easy to verify if you have a multimeter or continuity tester.

By convention, if the connected plug is carrying audio signals, the “tip” of the plug (connected to pin 3 of your connector) will be the audio signal and the “ring” (connected to pin 2 of the connector) will be ground.

A good explanation of this and other “audio jack” type connectors, can be found [on this DigiKey page](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/a-deep-dive-into-audio-jack-switches-and-configurations)

Comment: Thank you so much!!